# In MongoDB, is it possible to have a collection of variable objects?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Currently am using Mongoose but need to create a collection of variable objects:

I have products of different types and categories. Depending on the type and/or category, the review for the product will have a different data structure, to many different kinds of reviews to create an exhaustive list of review schemas in mongoose like the following two reviewSchema examples (after the productSchema example)

```
productSchema 
 {type: [string],
  category: [string],
  review: [reviewSchema (for certain type/category)]
  }
```

generic review schema:

```
example reviewSchema
{author: string,
date: Date.now,
rating: Number,
text: string
}
```

some categories or types will have reviews that have pros and cons:

```
example2 reviewSchema
{author: string,
date: Date.now,
rating: Number,
pros: [string],
cons: [string]
}
```

Can I make a collection of variable objects? Mongoose's rigid schema requirement doesn't seem to lend itself to providing an easy solution. Is it possible to make a collection of variable objects with mongojs?

Comment: It would be easier to do this when you just drop Mongoose and use MongoDB natively. Note that there is nothing which stops you from using both Mogoose and native MongoDB queries together in the same project.

Comment: So I can get the flexibility from mongoDB natively AND the query ease of Mongoose by only using mongoose for querying purposes ?